# groovy: use brackets on method calls or not?

Tags: groovy

this is a fairly general question about whether people should be using brackets on method calls that take parameters or not.
i.e.

```
def someFunc(def p) {
...
}
```

then calling:

```
someFunc "abc"
```

vs...

```
someFunc("abc")
```

Is this just a question of consistency, or is there specific use cases for each?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's primarily a question of consistency and readability, but note that Groovy won't always let you get away with omitting parentheses. For one, you can't omit parentheses in nested method calls:

```
def foo(n) { n }
println foo 1 // won't work
```

See the section entitled "[Omitting parentheses](http://www.groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_omitting_parentheses)" in the [Style guide](http://www.groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html).

Comment: I'm a fan of avoiding confusion.  Omitting parentheses has already caused a lot of confusion for new developers on our team. And there are only seemingly tightly defined use-cases for when you can (per the Style guide).

Answer (score 3):

There's no specific case where you must remove them, you can always use them. It's just prettier to leave them out.
There are cases where you can't do that (where you could confuse a list/map parameter with a subscript operator for instance, nested calls, or when the statement is an assignment), but the general rule is that the outmost call can have no parenthesis if there is no ambiguity.
(deleted several lines, as I've just received notification that there is a post already with that info)
Groovy 1.8 will allow even more cases to omit parenthesis, you can check them out at
http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/355001

Comment: ok, so could this be a extendability point then? just like the old issue with people not using opening and closing curly braces on ifs and loops? i.e. people should always use the brackets in the case where someone might have to just add them later...?

Comment: not sure if i get your point, if you mean if it would be better to use parentheses in a statement, say, `foo('x')` instead of `foo 'x'` because you might want to later write `println foo('x')` i'd say leave them out, use `foo 'x'` and add parentheses only when needed.

Answer (score 3):

["an empty pair of parentheses is just useless syntactical noise!"](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/style-guide.html#_omitting_parentheses)

It seems to me that they are encouraging you to use parenthesis when they serve a purpose, but omit them when they are just "noise"